# Converting audio files in an Amazon S3 bucket to wav

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I currently have an Amazon S3 bucket with these audio file types: .mp3, .gsm, .wav, .m4a, .mp4. Does anybody know of a way to either write a lambda script to convert all the files in the s3 bucket to .wav or another aws service that can convert it to .wav?
Let me know.

Answer (score 3):

[Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/introduction.html) service supports AAC, MP3, MP2, PCM, FLAC, and Vorbis audio codecs. Audio-only file formats supported include MP3, MP4, FLAC, OGA, OGG, and WAV.

Using Elastic Transcoder Service will make your life easy than writing AWS Lambda functions.